# How to remove "," in end of text in php?

Tags: php

I have a text:

```
"2G Network":"GSM 850","3G Network":"HSDPA 850",
```

How to remove "," in end of text in php

```
"2G Network":"GSM 850","3G Network":"HSDPA 850"
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim)

```
$str = rtrim($str, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is your friend.

```
$noComma = substr('"2G Network":"GSM 850","3G Network":"HSDPA 850",', 0, -1);
```

Comment: Not in this case.  In this case `rtrim` is OP's friend.

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's not the accepted answer, but the function still produces the exact result that the OP asked for.